# C++ and MySql++:: Segmentation error?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, mysql++

Okay, I just directly put my code here:

main.cpp

```
mysqlpp::Connection conn(false);

int main() {
if (conn.connect(DATABASE, HOST, DBUSER, DBPASS)) {
    Users a(conn, "test","pass");
    //a.authenticate();
```

and my Users.cpp:

```
Users::Users(mysqlpp::Connection conn, string username, string password) {
    this->conn = conn;
    this->username = username;
    this->password = password;
}
```

I can compile the program with no errors, but in command line, it says "Segmentation fault". Whats this error? and how to solve it?

Comment: Please try to debug your code to find out which statement is executed when your program hits the segmentation fault!

Comment: I strongly feel that its the Users contructor. If I exclude the constructor, the program has no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should store a pointer to a `mysqlpp::Connection` in your `Users` class then accept a pointer instead of a whole connection object in your constructor. Don't forget to update other references in your class implementation as well.

main.cpp:

replace

```
mysqlpp::Connection conn(false);
```

with

```
mysqlpp::Connection *conn = new mysqlpp::Connection(false);
```

Users.cpp

replace

```
Users::Users(mysqlpp::Connection conn, string username, string password) {
this->conn = conn;
```

with

```
Users::Users(mysqlpp::Connection *conn, string username, string password) {
this->conn = conn;
```

as long as in your Users.h it says something like this

```
class Users
{
    private:
        mysqlpp::Connection *conn; // <-- the star is important!
    // rest of class definition goes here
};
```

then you access the methods of `conn` like `conn->method()`

Comment: I hate pointers, thats the most difficult thing I ever learn in c++. Could you please show  me how to use pointer in my Users class?

Comment: @cpp_noob: a reference will do, too.  If you _solemnly_ hate pointers, walk away from programming, or try to read up and find the correspondence between C++ pointers, C# references, windows Handles, ...

Comment: @xtofl: I am new to C++. i though I am passing the connection as reference already? What do you mean by "reference"?

Comment: i added code to help explain how to use pointers in your situation. you should learn to love pointers because it's the only way to make real-world applications. you can't fit everything on the stack.

Comment: I dont get this line: " then you access the methods of conn like conn->method()" Conn methods????

Comment: instead of conn.method() its now conn->method()